# Overriding a NSMutableUrlRequest static initializer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutableurlrequest, static-initializer

Heres my scenario. Most of my network calls now need to have an api key inserted into the header field when making a request. So what i was thinking i could do was make a category of NSMutableUrlRequest. Override one of the initalizers. Then in that one initializer i could set the api key as a header field. So everytime i create an object of NSMUTABLEURLREQUEST the header field i need is already set. If you look at the apple doc here [NSMutableUrlRequest](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSURLRequest) you can see that the object has 4 initializers 2 class and 2 instance methods. Ill list my questions

1. What initializer function should i override in order to complete my task? The class or the instance ones?
2. How can i override it? Either if its an instance or class initializer?
3. Is this even a good way to go about it? or should i just subclass it and override it like that?

My code has been written for sometime now and well i dont want to go back and insert the api key into each individual request because well theres a lot of them. In a way i think this is a better approach to it because ill just have to set the apiKey in one place and not many place, which lessens the probability of a programming errors.Thank you for your help.

P.S. Even if this isnt a good way to complete this can someone still show me how a class initializer works? Like whats the underlying code so i can generate my own static class initializers also. Each time i try to override the class method i cant figure out what type to return.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Can you not loop through your creation process with your desired headers, inserting them? for (x in headers){ create request with x } - something like that?

Comment: No because all the requests are not in the same class. Ill just have to subclass NSURLRequest and add the api key. This will fix my issue plus i just read here on this [webpage](http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/categories) that its not good practice to override methods in a category. Since if you create another category off the same class objective c wont know which function to call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Categories are not meant to be used to override. You use categories when you want to add additional functionality to existing classes. If you really want to override the initializers then use inheritance.

The static functions are not initializers, they are just helper functions that creates the instance for you, so there's no need to handle them. The simple `initWithURL:` method is just a simplified version which provide default values for the designated initializer `initWithURL:cachePolicy:timeoutInterval:`; so in your subclass you actually only need to override this single initializer, looking something like this:

```
@interface MyNSMutableURLRequest : NSMutableURLRequest
@end

@implementation MyNSMutableURLRequest

- (instancetype)initWithURL:(NSURL *)URL cachePolicy:(NSURLRequestCachePolicy)cachePolicy timeoutInterval:(NSTimeInterval)timeoutInterval {
    self = [super initWithURL:URL cachePolicy:cachePolicy timeoutInterval:timeoutInterval];
    if (self) {
        //do your stuff here
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Your right i read online that its not good to override base classes since if you do and have to later on creat another category from the same class the compiler wouldnt know which method to use. So im just going to use inheritence.

Comment: I added the webpage in my comment in the original post if anyone wants to read it